# Азбучные истины

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Слова **алфавит** и **азбука** — синонимы. Почему же говорят "азбучные истины" и никогда — "алфавитные"? Только ли дело во времени появления слова в языке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.  
Дело, конечно, не только во времени появления выражения. Дело в том, что "азбучные" означает здесь не совсем то, что алфавитные.

Название "азбука" происходит от названий букв русского алфавита (Аз, Букы, Веди...). Для запоминания азбуки использовались т.н. азбучные стихи или молитвы, каждая строчка которых начиналась с очередной буквы алфавита, это были своего рода акростихи. Вот начало одного такого стиха-молитвы (из Вики):

Аз есть свет ми́ру
Бог есмь пре́жде всех век
Ве́даю всю та́йну в челове́це и мысль
Глаго́лю лю́дем зако́н Мой
Добро́ есть творя́щим во́лю Мою́
...

Каждая строчка представляла собой простую - и очевидную для запоминающего - мысль, т.е. безусловную **истину**. И исходно каждая такая мысль называлась **азбучной истиной**. Потом название было перенесено на любое очевидное утверждение.

Comment: Ай, молодца! Азбука (в отличие от алфавитов других языков)полна тайного смысла и читается. как послание. Причем разные толкователи по-разному ставят знаки препинания - и все равно получается связный, осмысленный, поучительный текст. Некоторые говорят о зашифрованном послании Бога.  Вот один из переводов:
Я знаю буквы: (Аз буки веди)
Письмо – это достояние. (Глаголь добро есть)
Трудитесь усердно, земляне, (живете зело)
Как подобает разумным людям - (Како люди мыслете)
Постигайте мироздание! 
Несите слово убежденно - 
Знание – дар Божий! 
Дерзайте, вникайте, чтобы 
Сущего свет постичь!

Comment: Т.е. наша азбука - это не просто набор букв в определенном  порядке, это текст,  запись основных истин, поучение! Азбука - уникальное творение! Восхищаюсь ею!

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, все-таки, что выражение "азбучные истины" появилось именно тогда, когда алфавит еще назывался азбукой. Кроме того, выражение это народное, а народу всегда были ближе русские слова, а не заимствования.

Answer (score 0):

Даааа....
Теперь становится понятным ,почему большевики превратили нашу азбуку в алфавит.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, название "азбучные истины" соответственно "начальным знаниям". Обучение чтению/письму начинается с азбуки.
А насчёт разницы алфавита, азбуки, абевеги см. на сайте: http://language.ucoz.ru/str3.html